# C# this[ ] Property in Java

Tags: java

Is there a java equivalent for following C# Code snippet?

```
    public Component this[Type type]
    {
        get
        {
            return Stuff;
        }
    }
```

so that I am able to request data with

```
objectInstance[typeof(ObjectClass)];
```

Comment: There is no Indexer in Java. You have to write your own get/set method.

Comment: Ok, thats a pitty. Thanks.

Comment: yeah it's pity but have faith in java :)

Comment: What does that do? I don't understand (don't know C#).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an indexer - it allows you to use array notation to retrieve (or set if the indexer has a 'set' block) data from the instance (most often, the indexer parameter would be an integer).

This indexer is called from C# as follows:

```
data = myInstance[someType];
```

If your indexer had a 'set' block, then you could set a value for the instance as follows:

```
myInstance[someType] = data;
```

The Java equivalent is:

```
public final Component getItem(java.lang.Class type)
{
    return Stuff;
}
```

and then call it:

```
data = myInstance.getItem(someType);
```

Comment: Yeah, just just a method. I wanted an indexer

Comment: @ThomasChristof: You don't have indexers in Java.  Methods are the Java alternative.